# How Can I using mbedTLS with lwip without RTOS?

Tags: c, tcp, lwip, mbedtls, cubemx

I want to use mbedtls with lwip in STM32F4 . And In the Cubemx, When I want to choose the mbedtls with lwip, I can not select middleware without FreeRTOS. But I dont want to use FreeRTOS. When I generate the code and delete the FreeRTOS file, folder etc.. I have lots of error. How can I use just lwip and mbedtls together ?

Comment: You can't. Mbed is a rtos itself.

Comment: But lwip has raw API solution and it support mbedtls and they talk about in their website https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__altcp__tls.html but how can i use I dont know

Comment: I have a same question. What is the solitions